# How to run nodemon in a web hosting

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

**I am making a website with a login form and I am trying to upload this into a webhosting**

To run my login form i need to use **node index**

How can I redirect my tag:

```
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="http://localhost:3000/">
        Sign up
      </a>
   </li>
```

How can I redirect this to my login form at `index.js` ? And how can I run node in a webhosting environment?

Comment: Does your hosting provider offer "node hosting" as a service? and if he does, is your "package" eligable for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I well understand your question. Why do you want to have `nodemon` on your hosting? Should you show your project structure? Why don't you just use links like so: `/` for index, `/signup` for sign up and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon is a development tool not meant for production. Nodemon makes sure the process will automatically restart when your code changes. There are better process managers are available which you can opt for like `pm2` for production.

And to redirect the page to login you could do something like this:

```
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/login')
});
```

**OR:**

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/login')
});
```